# Bootstrap tabbed form changes width

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, tabs

I'm making a tabbed form with Bootstrap. And I made a row that has two columns in it, one with a width of `col-md-9` and one where I put the form with a width of `col-md-3`. But when I put data in one of the tabs it makes that tab wider than the column of `col-md-3`. But I want the max width to be the `col-md-3` does anyone know what I did wrong?

This is what happens:
[image]

This my index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>        
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

        <title>Test Map</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jquery/jquery-ui.css">       
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/leaflet/leaflet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>    
    <!-- begin webviewer content -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- div voor de webmap -->
                <div class="col-md-9" id="map"></div>

                <!-- div voor het formulier -->
                <div class="col-md-3" id="form">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Legenda <i class="fa"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Layers <i class="fa"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Advanced selection <i class="fa"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                             <form action="javascript:submitQuery()">    
                                <fieldset class="form-group">
                                    <label for="distance">Show features within</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="distance" placeholder="enter km" name="distance"></input>
                                    <label for="featname">km of features named</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="featname" placeholder="Enter feature name" name="featname"></input>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">Submit</button>
                                </fieldset>
                             </form>
                            </div>  
                            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                                <h1>HIER MOET ZOOI VOOR TAB 2</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                                <h3>HIER MOET ZOOI VOOR TAB 3</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>     
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<!-- einde webviewer content -->

<!-- links naar scripts -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/leaflet/leaflet.0.7.3-src.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues is as you mentioned in your comment, the styling

`float:none;`

needed to be removed from your map id, to keep the formatting constant across different screen sizes.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. The "legenda" tab is still wider. But it's strange because when i make the div like this:

Comment: But it's strange because when i make the div: <div class="col-md-2" id="form"> it works.

Comment: That is strange, I updated my answer. The update should help. Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jcvWaTULbXyt2IuCyIPI?p=preview) This is what you were wanting to accomplish right?

Comment: Tryed that aswell, still the same problem. :(

Comment: Can you recreate the issue in a plunker?

Comment: It's weird because i copy paste the code in plunker and it functions but when i run it with xampp in my browser it doesn't

Comment: Do you have an idea cosmoss?

Comment: I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Did you try it Cosmoss?

Comment: Have you tried changing `container-fluid` to `container`? Let me know how that goes.

Comment: I changed it to container and the tabbs don't differ in  with anymore so that is fixed. But now my site is not full screen anymore it gives it the padding of the container i think.

Comment: So the width problem is fixed but now i have the full-screen problem xD

Comment: I solved the problem. I needed to delete float:none from my map div.

Comment: I still use the container-fluid layout and not the container layout because that gives some padding to the right and left i didn't want. But thanks for all the help Cosmoss!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My solution ended up being that I was mistakenly (out of habit) using a Bootstrap 3 tag (col-xs-12) instead of 4's col-12. Once changed the form sized as it should.